# How can I protect airbase on a 1x1 island from enemy ship attacks?

Tags: freeciv

Many turns ago, I established an airbase on a 1x1 island, and stationed about 20 stealth aircraft there. The base worked well for disrupting enemy shipping, but my opponents have now developed sufficient naval technology to directly attack my airbase using their naval units. How can I protect my aircraft from enemy ship attacks?